# Passing ngModel Template Reference Variable to Input Variable as AbstractControl

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to pass the `AbstractControl` referenced by `ngModel` to an Input variable on another component.

According to this: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation (second bullet under the code snippet), **`#name="ngModel"` exports NgModel into a local variable called `name`. `NgModel` mirrors many of the properties of its underlying `FormControl` instance, so you can use this in the template to check for control states such as valid and dirty**

If I'm reading that correctly, I should be able to pass the `FormControl` (which inherits from `AbstractControl`) in the `name` Template Reference Variable to another component, something like this: `<my-component for="name"></my-component>` where in the `MyComponent` class `for` is an `Input` variable taking an `AbstractControl`. I should then be able to work with `for` as an `AbstractControl`.

I can't.  When I debug, `for` is a string with the value "name".

Any ideas what I'm missing?  My goal is to be able to centralize validation handling and display in `MyComponent`, so I need access to the `AbstractControl` (or `FormControl`) for whatever field I'm attempting to validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need square brackets for `name` to be parsed, so

```
<my-component [for]="name"></my-component>
```

Otherwise, it;s treated as a string/

Comment: Oh, snap!  I was so focused on the "hard" stuff (or at least the stuff that was new to me) that I overlooked the simple thing!  This was *exactly* the problem.  Thanks @user184994.